# Retrieving content data from Umbraco using the Umbraco API in an ASP.NET site on another server

Tags: configuration, umbraco, asp.net-web-api

I have an Umbraco site deployed on my test server. I'm trying to pull content from the Umbraco site to a local ASP.Net webforms website I have on my local server using the Umbraco API.

I don't know where to specify the Umbraco web api endpoint, so the API will know to look for the service on the test server instead of my local server.

Is it possible to configure the Umbraco web api endpoint, and if so, how?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int documentID = 1077;
    var contentService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService; // NullReferenceException on this line, because the Current Application Context is null
    contentService.GetById(documentID);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an up to date version of Umbraco, you can create your own web API endpoints that you can call from remote servers. There is some basic documentation [here](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/WebApi/).